# ERROR: Native images generated against multiple versions of assembly System.Net.Http.Primitives

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-8.1

I got this error in my WP8.1 app,

> Application_UnhandledException
>   ERROR: Native images generated against multiple versions of assembly System.Net.Http.Primitives.
>      at CoolEditor.Class.DropNetRt.DropNetClient.LoadClient()
>      at CoolEditor.Class.DropNetRt.DropNetClient..ctor(String apiKey, String appSecret)
>      at CoolEditor.MainPage.d__6e.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.b__3(Object state)

And I have only one solution under the project.

Comment: I had a very similar problem after changing the configuration from Debug to Release before submitting a Windows Phone 8.1 Silverlight app.  It was resolved by cleaning the project and rebuilding it.

Comment: I am having the same problem

Answer (score 1):

Are you using a third party assembly that has a reference against a different version of System.Net.Http.Primities than the reference in your own project? Are any third parties being used that are not intended for use on the Windows Phone architecture?

Comment: This is my case - a WP8.1 app using Google.Apis.Auth.  Any remedy for this?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error, in my Xamarin.Forms solution after I've had retargeted my WindowsPhone project to Windows Phone 8.1 Silverlight.
The solution: I changed the portable projects targets property: changed from WindowsPhone silverlight 8 to Windows Phone silverlight 8.1

Comment: If I try that it just jumps back to WindowsPhone silverlight 8

Answer (score 0):

Make sure all your projects are using the same version of not just `Microsoft.Net.Http` but also:

```
Microsoft.Bcl.Build
```

and

```
Microsoft.Bcl
```

The error message can be a bit confusion on these cases.

Answer (score 0):

I occasionally have this error when deployinb a new version of Silverlight WP8.1 app to a WM10 phone.  Uninstalling the old version usually works thought it is not a desirable remedy.